# Form data to php variable

Tags: php, forms

I have a basic form on my index.html page asking for a user entered number. Seen below:

```
<html>    
<form action="display.php" method="post">
Number: <input type="text" name="number">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</html>
```

The php file is then going to check the number against if else statements in a function and echo if its a valid number or not. As seen below:

```
<?php
$number = $_POST["number"];

function numbercheck($number) {
//if else statements
}

numbercheck();
?>
```

So my question is, is this the correct way to assign the form data to the php variable so it can then be used in the function or am I completely doing it wrong.

Comment: you need to pass the variable to the function call also and return something.

Comment: You need to pass it like: `numbercheck($numbertocheck);`

Comment: should pass the post variable to the calling function `<?php


function numbercheck($number) {
//if else statements
}

numbercheck($_POST["number"]);
?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the proper way to get the posted data variable in php, Use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) before assigning `$_POST['number']` to a variable, this will prevent you from undefined errors..

```
<?php
$number='';
if(!empty($_POST["number"]))
{
    $number = $_POST["number"];
    numbercheck($number);
}


function numbercheck($number) 
{
//if else statements
}
?>
```

Second option that you want to change it to class and calling function in another file, then

In your `class.php` file :

```
<?php
   class Numbers {

      /* Member function*/
      function numbercheck($number)
      {
        //if else statements
      }
   }
?>
```

In your second file `index.php`

```
<?php 
include('class.php');
$Numbers = new Numbers; ///Here we have created new object

if(!empty($_POST["number"]))
{
    $number = $_POST["number"];
    $Numbers->numbercheck($number); ///access member function 
}
?>
```

Comment: `isset($_POST["number"]) &&` that's not needed. `!empty($_POST["number"])` is sufficient.

Comment: yes, there's no need to use both. I've tried now, only `empty` is sufficient.. Thank You @Fred-ii-

Comment: what you have write in your `numbercheck()` function ..?? @david

Comment: just going to ask but if i wanted to change this to a class to called on another php file, how would i edit the code above?

Answer (score 2):

Just pass $number to the function:

```
<?php
$number = $_POST["number"];
numbercheck($number);


function numbercheck($number) {
//if else statements
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP code you must pass  `$number` variable to function. like this :

```
<?php
   $number = $_POST["number"];

   // this is only declaration, not call
   function numbercheck($number) {
      //if else statements && return your answer
   }

   //here you are calling your function and displaying it on page
    echo numbercheck( $number );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I've stated in the comments, you need to pass the variable to the function:

```
$number = $_POST["number"];

numbercheck($number);

function numbercheck($number) {
    //if else statements

return true;
}
```